# GPG not decrypting PGP file in cmd line / script

Tags: security, encryption, gpg, pgp, public-key-encryption

Using Kleopatra / GPG4win

Have keys / secrets installed. Key trust is set to ultimate, validity is full, not expired. See it listed when doing gpg --list-secret-key and gpg --list-keys, everything looks good.

I am getting a file .pgp, from someone encrypting file with my provided key. I am able to right click the file and using Kleopatra (gui) and select decrypt and save file to new location and use the file, open file and read contents.

**Issue is when using cmd / script it errors out with :**

gpg: public key decryption failed: No secret key

gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Decrypted and moved: C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\folder_C\test_file_2024test.pgp

The script / cmd I am using is below, it does the following:

1. Decrypt PGP (failing)
2. Moved the decrypted file (.txt) to another location (fails cause file not decrypted)
3. then move the original file (pgp) to an archive location(works)

```
@echo off
set GPG_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
::change locations to correct spots
set SOURCE_FOLDER="C:\Folder_c\Folder_d"
set DECRYPTED_FOLDER="C:\Folder_B\testfilesdecrypted"
set GPG_FILES_FOLDER="C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\Archive"
set LOG_FILE="C:\Logs\PGP_log.txt"

if not exist %DECRYPTED_FOLDER% mkdir %DECRYPTED_FOLDER%
if not exist %GPG_FILES_FOLDER% mkdir %GPG_FILES_FOLDER%

:: Create or clear the log file
echo. > %LOG_FILE%
::watch the encryption type - this is PGP
:: Watch the type of encryption (0 for PGP)
for %%i in (%SOURCE_FOLDER%\*.pgp) do (
    %GPG_PATH% --decrypt --output %DECRYPTED_FOLDER%\%%~ni --batch --yes --passphrase "Never_gona_happen" "%%i" >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&1
    move "%%i" %GPG_FILES_FOLDER%
    echo Decrypted and moved: %%i >> %LOG_FILE%
)

echo Decryption, move, and file transfer completed. Check %LOG_FILE% for details.
```

The log file is showing me the error that the pgp file is not being decrypted. Log file shows the file was moved to archive also.

Thoughts on why it not working with script or possible changes?